# Unable to list parent directory from file path

Tags: java, android, mediastore

In my code am trying to collect all video file in list and warp it inside there parent directory and display it inside `recycler view`, And while displaying i get a folder name `0` i don't understand where the `0` folder comes from.

And the `0` folder list all files inside my storage, And those file are perfectly warped inside their respective folder.

> and here is a screen shot of the folder zero.

[image]

**code**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    foldersList = new ArrayList<>();
    folderpath = new ArrayList<>();

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    parseAllVideo();
    getUniqueFolders();
    adapter = new FolderAdapter(this, foldersList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

private void parseAllVideo() {
    try {
        String[] proj = {
                MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA};

        Cursor videocursor = this.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, null, null, null);
        if (videocursor != null) {
            if (videocursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int path_index = videocursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
                do {
                    String filepath = videocursor.getString(path_index);
                    String folder_path = MyUtils.getParentDirPath(filepath);
                    File file = new File(filepath);
                    if (file.exists()) {

                    }
                    folderpath.add(folder_path);
                } while (videocursor.moveToNext());
            }
            videocursor.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void getUniqueFolders() {
    List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>(folderpath));
    Collections.sort(newList);
    for (int i = 0; i < newList.size(); i++) {
        String folder_name = newList.get(i).substring(newList.get(i).lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        FolderModel folder = new FolderModel(folder_name, newList.get(i));
        Log.d(TAG, "base file = " + folder);
        foldersList.add(folder);
    }

}![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgQrz.jpg)
```

Here is what am trying to archive, the file in the internal folder is displayed as thumbnail by (glide, bit...) but with my code the `0` folder contains all file in my storage,

Here is what i want. [image]

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() value on most Android devices is `/storage/emulated/0`. All systems ok.

Comment: But I want eliminat the `0` I don't want to list it. How can it be done

Comment: The Camera folder in your recycleview is /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera.

Comment: Then remove it from the list. But you will loose the video files who reside there. Why are they not important? Or do not add "0" to the list. Easy to check

Comment: Your code will not work for Android Q and R so its time to program something new.

Comment: `Unable to list parent directory from file path` I do not understand the subject. There is nothing in your post describing such a problem.

Comment: @backapps the only reason I want to eliminate is the files inside camera folder are also listed inside `0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per @blackapps comment `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() value on most Android devices is /storage/emulated/0`

and when i checked my device storage and everthing was fine and the file is stored in internal storage location